# Why exactly was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

The question is [Is it right to say "Is John lie?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53555/is-it-right-to-say-is-john-lie)

The question is perfectly clear and has a perfectly clear answer.  I don't see any specific section of the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) that would indicate that the question is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: I voted as NARQ because the OP didn't offer any additional information that would have made it a good question

Comment: @JasperLoy the terms "reference" and "too basic" are not to be found in the FAQ.  There is a link to a question about resources for answering basic questions, and the only ones that seem relevant are Microsoft Word's grammar checker and CUP's *English Grammar in Use*, neither of which is a free on-line resource such as english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @simchona what additional information would you like to see?

Comment: phoog, the downvotes on Meta are different than on the main site. They are a sign of disagreement. Five people disagree with what you wrote.

Comment: Are you, phoog, the one who asked the question, even though your name at the question was lxhgy?

Comment: @Mitch If he didn't use an unregistered account to ask the question, then he is not the same user.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: OK. I got confused when he said "this question" I thought he was referring to the main site question, but no he's really talking about this question here on meta.

Comment: @Mitch Right. It's hard to understand what _this question_ means when they are referring to the question on the main site, and to the question on the meta site.

Comment: @phoog I asked what gave him the impression it was okay. Even with that, the question isn't very clear

Comment: @Mitch I am not the user who asked the question on english.se and yes, my edit was referring to this meta question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems pretty random to me, with no context for why one might think that construct is ok or where it was encountered.  (I didn't vote on it; it was already closed when I saw it.)

Comment: lxhgy says in a comment it was from a video. It would have been better if that was mentioned within the question and a link to video was given.

Answer (score 1):

I would have closed it as general reference as it is too basic, and can be answered by looking in a dictionary.

If the OP had ask if there are some dialects where "Is John lie?" is perfectly acceptable, that would have been different; as it is, the question is too basic, and you can get an answer by looking at the dictionary, and checking if *lie* is used as adjective.

It would have been also better if the OP had described exactly what question he had about that sentence (e.g. the usage of an infinitive after "I am," the usage of a noun after "I am").

Comment: I disagree.  I have known several non-native speakers who use the construction "I am *verb infinitive*", as in "I am drive to airport".  Such speakers would not be helped by checking if the word is available to use as an adjective, because they are not using it as an adjective.

Comment: The question is not about using an infinitive after _I am_; it's specifically about using _lie_ after _I am_. I think it's not in the advanced English classes where the construct "I am [infinitive]" is explained not to be correct.